# Passing arguments to both Bash and awk with $, references the wrong thing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to write a bash script to accept multiple sample names as parameters in order to call the files they correspond to and run a series of steps on those files. I know the steps work when running each step individually, but I'm trying to make things more automated.

I won't paste all of the steps here so it doesn't get too jumbled, because it looks like it's failing at the `awk` step in the following script because it's not substituting the right things in the right places.

I want `$SAMPLE` to come from inputs from the command line, and I want `$1` to reference the first field in the file I'm trying to call.

```
#!/bin/bash

for SAMPLE in "$@" 
do
    echo 'awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/$SAMPLE_filename.txt > pattern.txt'
    awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/$SAMPLE_filename.txt > pattern.txt
done
```

When I run this, I get the following errors when the program fails:

```
awk -F '\t' '{print 10-23Aug-PI}' /path/10-23Aug-PI/path/.txt > pattern.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/path/10-23Aug-PI/path/.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Obviously it's putting the file name as `$1` and then nothing as `$SAMPLE` unless I input multiple samples names when running the script.

So is there a way to rewrite the `awk` script or use something other than `awk` so that I can extract the first field in a file, but still pass parameters to the bash script from the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `set -x`, not `echo`, to log how your commands are executed. `echo`'s results are simply incorrect; they show substitutions that aren't actually happening, because the quoting for the echo is not the same as the quoting for the actual command.

Comment: Or: `printf '%q ' awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/$SAMPLE_filename.txt; echo` will do.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - this command did produce the correct log of the command instead of echo

Answer (score 0):

There is only one problem in your script. the variable `$SAMPLE_filename` is undefined. I assume you meant `${SAMPLE}_filename`. That is the reason why you get a file `.txt` and not `10-23Aug-PI_filename.txt`,

The reason why `$1` is substituted is due to the single quotes. If you count correctly your `echo` line, you notice that `$1` is unquoted, and hence substituted by the value `$1`. The `awk` will work as expected.

A corrected version of your script could be :

```
#!/bin/bash
for SAMPLE in "$@"; do
   echo "awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/${SAMPLE}_filename.txt > pattern.txt"
   awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/${SAMPLE}_filename.txt > pattern.txt
done
```

Comment: That looks like it worked - thank you so much!

Comment: never mind - I spoke too soon - I'm still seeing the following: awk -F t {print 10-23Aug-PI} /ufrc/cschnitzler/kelsey.yetsko/trimmed_reads/$SAMPLE/alignments_viral/${SAMPLE}_CP_all_viral_old.txt > pattern.txt
grep -f /ufrc/cschnitzler/kelsey.yetsko/trimmed_reads/pattern.txt /ufrc/cschnitzler/kelsey.yetsko/trimmed_reads/$SAMPLE/alignments_viral/hisat2_${SAMPLE}_viral_old.fasta > tmp.txt

Comment: You must have your quotes `'` wrong. As you use single quotes and from the message your write down, I can only concluded that most is between single quotes except the `print $1` part. The reason I say this is because strings between single quotes do not have any form of variable substitution. They are literal strings. This is a big difference with double quotes.

Comment: @K.Yetsko could you post your lines which produce the above result?

Comment: @K.Yetsko what your write down are also your `echo` lines. What is the content of `pattern.txt`

Comment: @K.Yetsko I have done a small update to the script above. Notice the double quotes in the `echo` line.

Comment: for SAMPLE in "$@"; do
 echo 'awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/${SAMPLE}_CP_all_viral_old.txt > pattern.txt'
 awk -F '\t' '{print $1}' /path/$SAMPLE/path/${SAMPLE}_CP_all_viral_old.txt > pattern.txt
 echo 'grep -f /path/pattern.txt /path/${SAMPLE}/path/hisat2_${SAMPLE}_viral_old.fasta > tmp.txt'
 grep -f /path/pattern.txt /path/${SAMPLE}/path/hisat2_${SAMPLE}_viral_old.fasta > tmp.txt
done

Comment: the pattern.txt is supposed to contain sequence ids, which is the first field in the tab delimited text file

Comment: look at the quotes in your echo line (`echo ' awk ... pattern.txt'`) and what I write (`echo "awk ... pattern.txt"`). Single vs. double quotes. Because you use single quotes, the `print $1` is actually unquoted. On top of that, single quotes do not have parameter expansion. So, `${SAMPLE}` is not replaced because it is part of a single quoted string.

Comment: you're right - it was an issue with the echo command, not the actual command I was trying to run. Everything is running smoothly now. Thank you